# ICEBERG - MERGE INTO doesn't work in Glue Job 4.0 from docker image aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01

Tags: database, aws-glue, apache-iceberg

I have an issue with **Glue Job** running from docker image amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01 while "**MERGE INTO**" **ICEBERG** table.

I follow the instruction from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/develop-and-test-aws-glue-version-3-0-jobs-locally-using-a-docker-container/.

My code contains of:

1. `CREATE TABLE {my_catalog}.{glue_database}.{table_name} ... TBLPROPERTIES ('table_type'='ICEBERG', ....` -> works
2. `spark.read.format("iceberg").load(f"{glue_database}.{table_name}") ....`  -> works
3. `spark.sql(f"""select * from {my_catalog}.{glue_database}.{table_name}""").show()`  -> works
4. ````
    my_df.createOrReplaceTempView('my_view'); 
        merge_query = f"""
            MERGE INTO {my_catalog}.{glue_database}.{table_name} t
            USING (select * from my_view) s
            ON (t.id = s.id)
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT *
        """; 
    spark.sql(merge_query);
    ``` ->  **ERROR**
   ````

1, 2, and 3 work in Docker. The issue arises only while running (4) from Docker; the code works perfectly for all 4 steps when running from the AWS Glue console.

```
ERROR: An error occurred while calling o45.sql.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: MERGE INTO TABLE is not supported temporarily.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.ddlUnsupportedTemporarilyError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:891)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies$BasicOperators$.apply(SparkStrategies.scala:895)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$1(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$3(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$folder$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:196)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$folder$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:194)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:199)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:192)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$2(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.createSparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:495)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$sparkPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:552)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:552)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$writePlans$5(QueryExecution.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$.append(QueryPlan.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.writePlans(QueryExecution.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$explainString(QueryExecution.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.explainString(QueryExecution.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$7(SQLExecution.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:615)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:615)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:591)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:222)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:622)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:617)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Additional information:

- In Docker & AWS Glue Job console I have:

  - AWS Glue version: 4.0
  - Iceberg version: 1.0.0
  - Spark version: 3.3.0-amzn-1
- My data are stored on s3 and iceberg is configured for this.

  - Iceberg config in python script.

    ```
    path_warehouse = f"s3://{bucket}/iceberg/warehouse"
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.defaultCatalog", my_catalog)
    spark.conf.set(f"spark.sql.catalog.{my_catalog}", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
    spark.conf.set(f"spark.sql.catalog.{my_catalog}.warehouse", f"{path_warehouse}/")
    spark.conf.set(f"spark.sql.catalog.{my_catalog}.catalog-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog")
    spark.conf.set(f"spark.sql.catalog.{my_catalog}.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO")
    ```
- From Docker, I am able to create tables and read data, but when trying to merge, it throws an error. From AWS Glue console everything works.
- I also tried configuration of glue job in docker: '--enable-glue-datacatalog', 'true' & '--datalake-formats', 'iceberg'.

Comment: Did you enable Hive support in your Spark Session inside the Glue Container? It should look something like the following: spark = (
        SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]")
        .appName("local-tests")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate()
    )

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, while running from docker container but not from the console. Wondering if you could make it work... I'm guessing it could be related to the iceberg version hosted in the container itself. I can select create table but not merge.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this from https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/big-data/develop-and-test-aws-glue-version-3-0-jobs-locally-using-a-docker-container/:
**Glue 4.0: Add native data lake libraries**
AWS Glue 4.0 Docker image supports native data lake libraries; Apache Hudi, Delta Lake, and Apache Iceberg.
You can pass the environment variable DATALAKE_FORMATS to load the relevant JAR files.

```
-e DATALAKE_FORMATS=hudi,delta,iceberg
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following to you Spark configuration:

```
SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")
```